# Get data from a text file in the fields

Tags: java

I'm working with text files and i need to get `float` and `int` datas from the files.

This is an example of my text file:

```
Total money: 800
ID: IT000323
Name: Steve
Age: 29
```

I need to get `800,IT000323,Steve and 29` , how can I do this?

Comment: You should take a look at the [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class

Comment: @Maze nothing,I have no idea how to do this :P,but I think i could search for the phrases and get the next word

Comment: See [File Read/Write Using FileInputStream/FileOutputStream](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/93/file-i-o/10225/file-read-write-using-fileinputstream-fileoutputstream#t=2016080210331317188) and [Reading a File with a Scanner](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/93/file-i-o/3704/reading-a-file-with-a-scanner#t=2016080210331317188) then try.

Comment: Is the text format is fixed or you can update it ? You should add some separator between value and id since you accept space in you id (`Total money`).

Comment: If this is a problem given to you, then ignore this comment, but don't you think you could save only the data in the file, and not the descriptions? That would save you a lot of effort when you read it back in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below class

```
 public static void getProperties(String infile) throws IOException {
        final int lhs = 0;
        final int rhs = 1;

        ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
        BufferedReader  bfr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(infile)));

        String line;
        while ((line = bfr.readLine()) != null) {
            if (!line.isEmpty()) {
                String[] pair = line.trim().split(":");
                list.add(pair[rhs].trim());
            }
        }

        bfr.close();

        System.out.println(list.toString());
    }
```

It will return values like

> [800, IT000323, Steve, 29]

String infile will contain the path of the file. For example: **D:\test.txt**

Answer (score 0):

You can just declare a regex with groups such as this:

```
"Total money: ([0-9]*) ID: (.*) Name: (.*) Age: ([0-9]*)";
```

Then you just have to match each file line with it and get every group in order. You can just use the [Pattern API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) if you are using at least Java 7

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
try (Scanner sc = new Scanner("Total money: 800 ID: IT000323 Name: Steve Age: 29")){
    sc.useDelimiter("((^| )[^\\:]+\\: )");
    int money = sc.nextInt();
    String id = sc.next();
    String name = sc.next();
    int age = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("money: " + money + " id: " + id  + " name: " + name + " age: " + age);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```